# Removing brackets and comma from a list of strings (python & sqlite)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Trying to make list 1, into list 2 shown in the code below by removing the brackets and commas within the brackets so I can use the strings for SQLite select queries:

```
[('Mark Zuckerberg',), ('Bill Gates',), ('Tim Cook',), ('Wlliam Sidis',), ('Elon Musk',)]
['Mark Zuckerberg', 'Bill Gates', 'Tim Cook', 'William Sidis', 'Elon Musk']
```

Comment: `[thing[0] for thing in list1]`? You have a list of tuples. You're not *"removing brackets and comma"*, you're extracting the first value from the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

While fetching row and storing in list use str(row)

```
list=[('Mark Zuckerberg',), ('Bill Gates',), ('Tim Cook',), ('Wlliam Sidis',), ('Elon Musk',)]
listoutput=[i[0] for i in list]
print(listoutput)
```

> Check output below

```html
<iframe height="400px" width="100%" src="https://repl.it/repls/PortlyCarefulCodegeneration?lite=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This -

```
region=['INDIA','ME',"SEA","AFRICA","SAARC","LATIN AMERICA"]
print region
lst= str(region)
lst.strip("[").strip("]").strip("'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list like this one,

```
animal_raw = [('cat', ), ('dog', ), ('elephant', )]
```

And now we will convert it into the one you asked that is without commas and parenthesis.

```
animal = [i[0] for i in animal_raw]
```

Now , `print(animal)`.
You should now get the output,

```
['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from a tuple  we can access the element by index as `tuple[index]`

single element tuples python represent as

```
(element,)
```

you have list of tuples

```
a = [('Mark Zuckerberg',), ('Bill Gates',), .... ]
b=[]
for i in a :
    b.append(i[0])

print(b)
```

or  short version

```
b = [i[0] for i in a]
```